# Get Uniqie views and views in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, visitor-statistic

I would like to retrive uniqie views and views in a single query.
My current query to retrive views looks like this, but i would also like to retrieve unique views with it.

The field to the IP address is called IP

```
SELECT `time` - `time` % 86400 AS Date, count(*) AS Views 
    FROM `bvcms_pageviews` 
    WHERE 1=1 
    GROUP BY Date
```

Best regards

Comment: Side note: If you're going to make your `WHERE` statement always evaluate to true, why even specify it? Just remove the `WHERE` completely.

Comment: Its 1=1 atm but it it will be changed to get specific dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique IP view data? Selected 'Distinct' would help with this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT IP, `time` - `time` % 86400 AS Date, count(IP) AS
 Views FROM `bvcms_pageviews` WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY Date
```

http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/